# Naming a data.frame column from within function that creates it

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

The code below creates a dataframe with my lagged data but to get the names fixed up I currently have to explicitly create the names with a second 'for' command. I'd like to move the column name creation inside of the function that creates the new column. Is that possible?

For instance, instead of calling MyLag(Close[,1], i) I'd like to call a new function MyLagNamed(Close[,1], i,"C") and the column is returned with the name set like in the example code.

Is that possible?

Thanks

```
MyLag <- function(x, k) c(rep(NA, k), x[1:(length(x)-k)] )

MaxColumns = 6

Close = structure(list(Close = c(12.8125, 12.97, 13.345, 13.625, 13.4375, 
                     13.6875, 13.75, 13.625, 13.3125, 13.875, 13.875, 13.9375, 13.875, 
                     14.3125, 14.6875, 14.375, 14.4075, 14.095, 14.4375, 14.375)), 
                     .Names = "Close", row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")

for (i in 1:MaxColumns) Close[i+1] <- MyLag(Close[,1], i)

for (i in 2:MaxColumns) colnames(Close)[i] = paste("MyLag(C,",i,")",sep="")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use curly braces `{}` to move the naming argument inside the `for` loop.

```
for (i in 1:MaxColumns) {
    Close[i+1] <- MyLag(Close[,1], i)
    colnames(Close)[i+1] = paste("MyLag(C,",i+1,")",sep="")
}
```

But this seems like a bad way of doing things. This is not *that* much better, but we also include a function argument to name the columns, like so:

```
MyLag <- function( x , k , name = "C"){
    j <- 0:6
    k <- k[ , ncol(k) ]
    df <- data.frame( lapply( j , function(x) (c( rep( NA , x ) , k ))[1:length(k)] ) )
    names( df ) <- c( "Close" , paste("MyLag(" , name , 1:x , ")",sep="") )
    return(df)
}
```

Which gives us a data.frame which looks like:

```
head( MyLag( 6 , Close , "High" ) , n = 7 )
    Close MyLag(High1) MyLag(High2) MyLag(High3) MyLag(High4) MyLag(High5) MyLag(High6)
1 12.8125           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA
2 12.9700      12.8125           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA
3 13.3450      12.9700      12.8125           NA           NA           NA           NA
4 13.6250      13.3450      12.9700      12.8125           NA           NA           NA
5 13.4375      13.6250      13.3450      12.9700      12.8125           NA           NA
6 13.6875      13.4375      13.6250      13.3450      12.9700      12.8125           NA
7 13.7500      13.6875      13.4375      13.6250      13.3450      12.9700      12.8125
```

Comment: While that works technically in this case I have a lot of functions so I'd like the function itself to create the name, if possible. In your solution above it requires that everytime I call MyLag that I get the stuff in the paste() written the same way. (I.e. - I lag Open, High, Low, Close so I have to do things many times instead of just once in the function call)

Comment: @LGTrader check the edit. I think the function I posted is more extensible, but I don't  really understand what you are asking. If you could clarify then I can better help you. What do you mean by high low etc. How are these used in the function?

Comment: Simon - you're solution is much closer to what I'm looking for. I don't think it's quite right yet, but that's likely because I didn't explain enough initially. In my case the data (Open, High, Low, Close) is price data from a stock. It's what you see on a chart when you look online, etc. In the dataframe time runs down the row side and MyLag shifts the data down correctly creating a copy of the data delayed by 1/2/3/ days etc.  I often need to lag all the price types (O/H/L/C) and then add them into the price dataframe to do calculations on the data over time.

Comment: After playing around with it I'm just going to use the curly brace change. It's clean enough and for a non-programmer like me I think easier to maintain over time. Thanks for your help Simon.